# Delete apex class in Production with Force.com IDE

Tags: apex, force.com, class, ide

Hi I am trying to delete the following APEX class in production and I'm getting the following error.

**Steps taken:**

1. loaded apex class
2. updated status of Meta datga xml file from "Active" to "Deleted"

**Error message:**

Run Failures:
  CustomQuoteAfter. line 2, column 35: trigger body is invalid and failed recompilation: Invalid type: CustomQuoteService

**Deployment Log:**

## Deploy Results:

```
File Name:    classes/CustomQuoteService.cls
Full Name:  CustomQuoteService
Action:  NO ACTION
Result:  SUCCESS
Problem: n/a

File Name:    package.xml
Full Name:  package.xml
Action:  UPDATED
Result:  SUCCESS
Problem: n/a
```

**# Test Results:
Run Failures:
  CustomQuoteAfter. line 2, column 35: trigger body is invalid and failed recompilation: Invalid type: CustomQuoteService**

**APEX CLASS**

```
public with sharing class CustomQuoteService {
  public void processTriggerAfter(SBQQ__Quote__c[] quotes, Map<Id,SBQQ__Quote__c> oldMap) {
    Map<Id,SBQQ__Quote__c> quotesById = new Map<Id,SBQQ__Quote__c>(quotes);
    SBQQ__Quote__c[] changedServiceLevel = new SBQQ__Quote__c[0];
    for (SBQQ__Quote__c quote : quotes) {
      SBQQ__Quote__c old = oldMap.get(quote.Id);
      if (quote.Service_Level__c != old.Service_Level__c) {
        changedServiceLevel.add(quote);
      }
    }

    if (!changedServiceLevel.isEmpty()) {
      Map<String,Product2> productsByKey = new Map<String,Product2>();
      for (Product2 product : 
        [SELECT SBQQ__SubscriptionCategory__c, SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c,
           Service_Level__c, Term_Type__c, SBQQ__SubscriptionPercent__c, SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c
         FROM Product2 WHERE SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c != null AND IsActive = true]) {
        productsByKey.put(generateKey(product), product);
      }

      Map<String,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> linesByKey = new Map<String,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>();
      SBQQ__QuoteLine__c[] lines = [SELECT SBQQ__Product__r.SBQQ__SubscriptionCategory__c, SBQQ__Product__r.SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c,
                            SBQQ__Product__r.Service_Level__c, SBQQ__Product__r.Term_Type__c, SBQQ__Quote__c
                           FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c
                           WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c IN :changedServiceLevel AND SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c != null];
      for (SBQQ__QuoteLine__c line : lines) {
        SBQQ__Quote__c old = oldMap.get(line.SBQQ__Quote__c);
        SBQQ__Quote__c quote = quotesById.get(line.SBQQ__Quote__c);
        if (line.SBQQ__Product__r.Service_Level__c == old.Service_Level__c) {
          String key = generateKey(line, quote.Service_Level__c);
          Product2 newMaint = productsByKey.get(key);
          System.assert(newMaint != null, 'No product: ' + key);
          if (newMaint != null) {
            line.SBQQ__Product__c = newMaint.Id;
            line.SBQQ__SubscriptionPercent__c = newMaint.SBQQ__SubscriptionPercent__c;
            line.SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c = newMaint.SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c;
          }
        }
      }
      update lines;
    }
  }

  private String generateKey(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c line) {
    return generateKey(line, line.SBQQ__Product__r.Service_Level__c);
  }

  private String generateKey(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c line, String serviceLevel) {
    return line.SBQQ__Product__r.SBQQ__SubscriptionCategory__c + '-' + line.SBQQ__Product__r.Term_Type__c + '-' + line.SBQQ__Product__r.SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c + '-' + serviceLevel;
  }

  private String generateKey(Product2 product) {
    return product.SBQQ__SubscriptionCategory__c + '-' + product.Term_Type__c + '-' + product.SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c + '-' + product.Service_Level__c;
  }

  testMethod static void test() {
    Product2 p1 = new Product2(Name='Test1',Service_Level__c='Test',SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c='Percent Of Total');
    Product2 p2 = new Product2(Name='Test1',Service_Level__c='TestPlus',SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c='Percent Of Total');
    insert new Product2[]{p1,p2};

    Account customer = new Account(Name='Test',BillingCountry='USA',Industry='Software');
    insert customer;

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='Test',AccountId=customer.Id,CloseDate=System.today(),StageName='Prospecting');
    insert opp;

    SBQQ__Quote__c quote = new SBQQ__Quote__c(SBQQ__Opportunity__c=opp.Id,Service_Level__c='Test');
    insert quote;

    SBQQ__QuoteLine__c line = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c(SBQQ__Quote__c=quote.Id,SBQQ__Product__c=p1.Id);
    insert line;

    quote.Service_Level__c = 'TestPlus';
    update quote;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete Apex Class from Prodcution with Force.com IDE successful but still active in Production Environment](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107851/delete-apex-class-from-prodcution-with-force-com-ide-successful-but-still-active)

Comment: I have closed the duplicate. Do not close this one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a trigger "CustomQuoteAfter" that calls this class?
If so, remove the reference from the trigger.